# Geofence registration was successful, but geofence does not call onHandleIntent

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-geofence

I register geofence this way:

```
GeofencingClient client = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context);
GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
            builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
            builder.addGeofence(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(buildRequestId(objectId))
                    .setCircularRegion(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 500)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
            client.addGeofences(builder.build(), PendingIntent.getService(context, objectId,
                    new Intent(context, HomeGeofenceService.class).putExtra(KEY_OBJECT_ID, objectId), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    ObjectManager.getInstance(objectId).setLocationNotifEnabled(false);
                    ObjectManager.save();
                    int statusCode = -1;
                    if (e instanceof ApiException)
                        statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(UiConstants.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR).putExtra(KEY_CODE, statusCode));
                }
            });
```

**Service in manifest:**

```
<service android:name=".services.HomeGeofenceService"/>
play services version: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

**Service:**

```
public class HomeGeofenceService extends IntentService {
public HomeGeofenceService() {
        super(HomeGeofenceService.class.getSimpleName());
    }
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { /***some code**/ }
}
```

**List of permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

**targetSdkVersion 27**

This code was working fine in our app from April 19th. Can this issue be connected to the fact that we're in russian region? With all IP bans. Or maybe there is some other issue here?

Comment: Did you give Geofences the required permissions?

Comment: Yeah. Updated the question with information.

Comment: ok. What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 27